# wrapper to c++/cli

Tags: c++-cli, wrapper

What is the basic structure of a wrapper to c++/cli so it can be called from c# ?

Comment: Do you want to wrap an *unmanaged* class in a C++/CLI wrapper to let C# use it? Or do you simply want to use a C++/CLI class from C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A wrapper for a C++ class Blah:

**EDIT:**

```
ref class BlahWrapper {
  BlahWrapper () {
     blah = new Blah();
  }

  !BlahWrapper() { //Destructor called by GC
     if (blah != null) {
         delete blah;
         blah = null;
     }
  }

  ~BlahWrapper() { //Dispose() called in "using" blocks,  or manually dispose
     if (blah != null) {
         delete blah;
         blah = null;
     }
  }

  private:
  Blah* blah;
}
```

Comment: Setting `blah = NULL;` after deleting would be nice. Also GC needs `!BlahWrapper()` destructor.

Comment: !BlahWrapper compiles into Dispose().... GC uses a normal destructor to destroy the object... And again, it's being deleted, the variable blah won't exist after that line.

Comment: What do you mean by "a normal destructor." "!BlahWrapper" compiles into `Finalize()` which is invoked by GC. http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/199601976;jsessionid=GEMCVL2U30511QE1GHPCKHWATMY32JVN?pgno=4  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177197(v=VS.90).aspx Unmanaged memory should be released in `!BlahWrapper()` which is the finalizer. If you release blah in destructor then setting it to NULL means telling GC that you have nothing to do with `blah` anymore.

Comment: Of course your code is not wrong. It will work without trouble if and only if OP deletes the instances of BlahWrapper himself. If not GC never frees the native or unmanaged resources, in this particular case `blah` pointer.