# Create Managed Object From Unmanaged Class Function

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I am trying to create a Managed C++/CLI object in unmanaged code.

1. Is this possible?
2. If so, am I doing it right? see code below

   ```
   #include <vcclr.h>
   #include <ManagedClass.h>

   // compiled with /clr
   namespace X 
   {
       class UnmanagedClass
       {
           UnmanagedClass(){}
           ~UnmanagedClass(){}

           gcroot<Y::ManagedClass^> m_guiControl;

           void functionA()
           {
                m_guiControl = new gcroot<Y::ManagedClass^>;
           }
       }
   }

   // compiled into Managed dll with /clr
   // in file ManagedClass.h in a separate project
   using namespace System::ComponentModel;
   // more usings here ..etc

   namespace Y {
       public ref class ManagedClass : public System::Windows::Forms::UserControl
       {
           // implementation here

       }
   }
   ```

When I compile the `UnmanagedClass` source file, I keep getting a whole lot of errors with the first one being `error C2039: 'ComponentModel' : is not a member of 'System'`. How come it is not recognising `ComponentModel`?

I thought this was suppose to be IJW (it just works) ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example for a wrapper:

```
class UnmanagedClass
{
    gcroot<ManagedClass^> m_managed;

public:
    UnmanagedClass() 
    {
       m_managed = gcnew ManagedClass();
    }
};
```

Look here:

[C++/CLI - Managed class to C# events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451546/c-cli-manged-class-to-c-events)

[wrapper to c++/cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985907/wrapper-to-c-cli/4985940#4985940)

**Edit**:

When you get an error on a using statement, and you know it's supposed to exist, It's usually because that dll isn't referenced.

Go to the projects references, choose add reference.

You can add .Net assemblies in the .Net tab. Find the one you need and add it.

Comment: Updated question - it still doesn't work, it doesnt seem to recognise all the using statements in the managed C++ object..

Comment: it's not enough to add using directives. you need to add references to the appropriate .NET assembly for your VC++ project.

Comment: Yay! thanks Marius that is the answer I was looking for. Same as for a C# .NET except I didn't know how to do it for a C++ project. You should put that down as an answer.